# Are bearer authentication tokens encrypted by default using OWIN?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

We're using Web API 2 and OWIN bearer authentication. Inside our OAuthAuthorizationProvider class, we're adding claims the normal way.

```
OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = async context =>
{

//Authenticate the user
//Our logic removed

//After authenticating, set up the claims
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("user", authenticatedUser.Username));
context.Validated(claimsIdentity);

}
```

My question - **is the generated bearer token encrypted by default?** Also, since it may be related, is there any advantage to using `context.Validated(authenticationTicket)` instead?